# Clone div with jQuery and increase child classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML is:

```
<div id="product">
<div class="clonedInput" id="input">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">

                    {!! Form::label('product','Product: ') !!}
                    <select name="product" size="1">
                        @foreach($products as $p)
                        <option value="{{ $p->name }}">{{ $p->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                    {!! Form::label('prodquant','Product Quantity: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::input('number','prodquant','1', ['class' => 'form-control', 'step' => 'any'])
                     !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                    {!! Form::label('proddescription','Description: ') !!}
                    {!! Form::textarea('proddescription',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="removebtn"></div>
</div>
```

And my jQuery is:

```
var rowNum = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    rowNum++;
    $(".cloneme").click(function(){
       var nextHTML = $(".clonedInput").clone()/*.appendTo("#product")*/;
       nextHTML.attr('id','input' + rowNum).appendTo('#product');
    });
});
```

It works fine at duplicating the .clonedInput div, but I need the child classes of .product, .prodquant and .proddescription to increase along with the #input.

And if anyone can point me into the right direction of how to get a remove button in there, I'd be most grateful!!

Comment: Tip: consider using template tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) for "cloneable" elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use classes instead of `id`'s so you don't have to increase anything :

```
$(".cloneme").click(function(){
    $('#product').append($(".clonedInput").clone());
});
```

If you've realy to increase the classes for another purpose you just do it like :

```
$(".cloneme").click(function(){
    var nextHTML = $(".clonedInput").clone();

    nextHTML.attr('id','input' + rowNum);
    nextHTML.find('.product').attr('class','product' + rowNum);
    nextHTML.find('.prodquant').attr('class','prodquant' + rowNum);
    nextHTML.find('.proddescription').attr('class','proddescription' + rowNum);

    nextHTML.appendTo('#product');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to increase the number for when I handle the data from the form later on, otherwise i only get one product rather than several

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much!